# Function to INSERT dynamic list of columns in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, insert, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I want to do [something like this](http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_stored_procedure_INSERT.php) in PostgreSQL.

I tried this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION create_patient(_name text, _email text, _phone text
     , _password text
     , _field1 text, _field2 text, _field3 timestamp, _field4 text
     , OUT _pid integer, OUT _id integer
    ) RETURNS record AS
$$
DECLARE
    _id integer;
    _type text;
    _pid integer;
BEGIN
    _type := 'patient';

    INSERT into patients (name, email, phone, field1, field2, field3)
    VALUES (_name, _email, _phone, _field1, _field2, _field3)
    RETURNING id into _pid;

    INSERT into users (username, password, type, pid, phone, language)
    VALUES (_email, _password, _type, _pid, _phone, _field4)
    RETURNING id into _id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But there are a lot of instances where I would not want to specify some of `field1 / field2 / field3 / field4` and want the unspecified fields to use the default value in the table. Currently that is not possible, because to call this function I need to specify all fields.

Is there a simple way to create a wrapper procedure for `INSERT` in PL/pgSQL where I can specify which fields I want to insert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**default values**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) for function parameters and [**dynamic SQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) ...

#### Demo function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_patient(
     _name     text      = NULL  -- always updated, NULL if not provided
    ,_email    text      = NULL
    ,_phone    text      = NULL
    ,_password text      = NULL
    ,_field1   text      = NULL  -- variable parameters
    ,_field2   text      = NULL
    ,_field3   timestamp = NULL
    ,_language text      = NULL
    ,_cols     text[]    = '{field1,field2,field3,language}'
    ,OUT _pid  text
    ,OUT _id   int)
  RETURNS record AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
   'INSERT INTO patients (field1, field2, field3, name, email, phone)
    VALUES               (%s,     %s,     %s,     $4,   $5,    $6   )
    RETURNING id'
       ,CASE WHEN 'field1' = ANY(_cols) THEN '$1' ELSE 'DEFAULT' END
       ,CASE WHEN 'field2' = ANY(_cols) THEN '$2' ELSE 'DEFAULT' END
       ,CASE WHEN 'field3' = ANY(_cols) THEN '$3' ELSE 'DEFAULT' END)
    INTO  _pid                       -- return value, also used in 2nd insert
    USING _field1, _field2, _field3, _name, _email, _phone;

   EXECUTE format(
   'INSERT INTO users (username, password, type,        pid, phone, language)
    VALUES            ($1,       $2,       $$patient$$, $3,  $4,    %s      )
    RETURNING id'
      ,CASE WHEN 'language' = ANY(_cols) THEN '$4' ELSE 'DEFAULT' END)
    INTO  _id                        -- return value
    USING _email, _password, _pid, _phone, _language;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Call

```
SELECT * FROM create_patient('myname','myemail','myphone','mypassword'
,'myfield1','myfield2',NULL,'English','{field2,language,field1}'::text[]);
```

As the function uses named parameters and each has a default value, you can even call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM create_patient(_name := 'myname');
```

May not work for your tables if some non-null values are required, but goes to demonstrate that you can omit any parameters with defaults on them once you provide named parameters. Omitted parameters take the default value as declared (not to be confused with column defaults). More in this related answer:
[Functions with variable number of input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782199/functions-with-variable-number-of-input-parameters/16789179#16789179)

#### Major points

- Make use of the [`DEFAULT` keyword of the `INSERT` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html). It makes the system insert the column default of the table.
  Alternative would be to only list columns in the `INSERT` line that get a corresponding item in the `VALUES` line.
- You *have to* use [dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to manipulate the statement itself, not just the values.
- "Swing columns" are `field1` to `field3` and `language`, the rest is hardwired as per definition. Vary as needed.
- My function works for *all cases*, you can even provide a `NULL` value instead of the column default. That requires a parameter `_cols` providing the information which columns are to be be inserted.
- If all involved columns were declared `NOT NULL` - which has not been clarified - you can simplify: pass `NULL` for any column that should get the column default and adapt the `CASE` statements.
- If you omit `_cols`, all fields will be inserted. As `_cols` is the last `IN` parameter and has a default value, you can *always* omit it.
- I employ the [`USING` clause for `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to pass parameters as *values* and prevent SQL injection with dynamically built query strings.
- I employ `format()` to simplify statement assembly and avoid multiple assignments. Cheaper in PL/pgSQL.
- Don't `DECLARE` `_id` and `_pid` in the function body, since they are declared by `OUT` parameters in the header and returned automatically.
- You can insert a constant value for `type` in the `INSERT` statement directly. This way you don't need *any* variables and save additional assignments.
- Tested with PostgreSQL **9.1**, but should work with all versions since 8.4 - except for [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) which was introduced with 9.1.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the extremely detailed response. I think this would do the trick! And yes, most of my columns are NOT NULL and have a default value set in the table - which was the problem.