# Functions with variable number of input parameters

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm creating a stored procedure (function) in a PostgreSQL DB, which updates a table depending on its input. In order to create a variable number of parameter function, I'm creating an extra input parameter called mode, which I use to control which parameters I use on the update query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_site(
    mode integer,
    name character varying,
    city character varying,
    telephone integer,
)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
BEGIN
IF mode = 0 THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Sites" SET 
    ("City","Telephone") = (city,telephone)
    WHERE "SiteName" = name;
    RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Error on site update: %, %',SQLERRM,SQLSTATE;
    RETURN 0;
END;
ELSIF mode = 1 THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Sites" SET "City" = city
    WHERE "SiteName" = name;
    RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Error on site update: %, %',SQLERRM,SQLSTATE;
    RETURN 0;
END;
    ELSIF mode = 2 THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Sites" SET "Telephone" = telephone
    WHERE "SiteName" = name;
    RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Error on site update: %, %',SQLERRM,SQLSTATE;
    RETURN 0;
END;
    ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'Error on site update: %, %',SQLERRM,SQLSTATE;
    RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What would be best? To create a function `update_site(<all the columns of table>)` and a separate function `update_site(id integer, <varchar column to update>)`, or use the mode in one function to define the difference? Which option is more efficient? One unique function or different ones for each purpose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Advanced features like `VARIADIC` or even [polymorphic input types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#id-1.8.3.7.18) and dynamic SQL are very powerful. The last chapter in this answer provides an advanced example:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

For a simple case like yours, you can just use **default values** for function parameters. It all depends on exact requirements.
**If** the columns in question are all defined `NOT NULL`, this would probably be simpler and faster:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_site(_name      text  -- always required
                                     , _city      text DEFAULT NULL
                                     , _telephone int  DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _city IS NULL AND _telephone IS NULL THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'At least one not-null input value required!';
      RETURN;  -- nothing to update
   END IF;

   UPDATE "Sites"
   SET    "City"      = COALESCE(_city, "City")
        , "Telephone" = COALESCE(_telephone, "Telephone")
   WHERE  "SiteName"  = _name;
END
$func$;
```

Read about [default values in the manual!](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

To avoid naming conflicts between parameters and column names I make it a habit to prefix input parameters with `_`. That's a matter of taste and style.

- The first parameter `name` has no default, since it is required at all times.
- Other parameters can be omitted.
- At least one is required, or a `WARNING` is raised and nothing else happens.
- The `UPDATE` will only change columns for given parameters.
- Can easily be expanded for *N* parameters.

### Function call

Three options:

1. [**Positional notation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-POSITIONAL)
   Is the simple way, but it only allows to omit the rightmost parameter(s):

   ```
   SELECT update_site('foo', 'New York');  -- no telephone
   ```
2. [**Named notation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-NAMED)
   Allows to omit *any* parameter that has a default value:

   ```
   SELECT update_site(name => 'foo', _telephone => 123);  -- no city
   ```
3. [**Mixed notation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-MIXED)
   Combines both:

   ```
   SELECT update_site('foo', _telephone => 123);  -- still no city
   ```

Up to **Postgres 9.4**, **`:=`** was used instead of **`=>`** for assignment in the call:

```
SELECT update_site(name := 'foo', _telephone := 123);
SELECT update_site('foo', _telephone := 123);
```

Still valid in Postgres 15 for backward compatibility, but rather use modern syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like a really good solution for my question. Do default values can be used on other database programming languages, other than PostgreSQL?

Comment: @kzz: These rules apply to PostgreSQL functions only. Other RDBMS have embedded procedural languages, too. Oracle's PL/SQL is the closest, PL/pgSQL was modeled after that. Not sure how PL/SQL or MS tSQL handle default values. The concept of default values is undoubtedly more wide-spread than `VARIADIC` or polymorphic parameters.

Comment: I decided to change my accepted answer to this one because its more detailed in answering my question.

Comment: Nice... I somehow managed to miss the support for default parameters entirely.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you'll want to look into:

- Dynamically building the SQL using the `format` function and its `%I` and `%L` specifiers, then executing it with `EXECUTE ... USING`; and
- Using `VARIADIC` parameters to take variable numbers of arguments to the function, with the caveat that they must all be the same data type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found information on EXECUTE format, and can accomplish what I asked for variable parameters, but since EXECUTE is recalculated every time the function is executed, I guess ultimately it would be less efficient than normal functions. I wanted to know if that was possible, but for what I am being asked it is more than needed. Anyways, thanks. I will definitely read more about it, though. Seems interesting.

Comment: @kzz Yep, it's a useful facilility, but be careful to use `EXECUTE ... USING` or the safe format parameters to avoid accidental SQL injection exposure via in-database dynamic SQL.

Comment: great answer!!!