# pg_query_params fails with too many arguments

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm not sure why this is failing, I have two examples, they are the same function, but one works and the other doesn't work. I really want the one that doesn't work to work, because it will allow me to put a lot of my potentially repetitive code into a single function.

This calls either `setItemWorks` or `setItemDoesNotWork`.

```
public function setitemName($itemId, $name){
    /* Add the name of the item to the database */

    $fieldName = 'name';
    $tableName = "items";
    $idName = "id";

    $result = $this->setItemWorks($itemId, $name);
    // Use comments to enable below function and disable function call above.
    //$result = $this->setItemDoesNotWork($tableName, $idName, $fieldName, $itemId, $name);

}
```

**setItemDoesNotWork:**

```
private function setItemDoesNotWork($table, $id, $field, $itemId, $fieldValue){

    $_1 = $itemId;
    $_2 = $fieldValue;
    $_3 = $field;
    $_4 = $table;
    $_5 = $id;

    $parameters = array($_1, $_2, $_3, $_4, $_5);

    // If the ID already exists, then update the name!
    $sql = 'update $4 set $3 = $2 where $5 = $1;';
    pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);

    // Add ID and Name into table.
    $sql = 'insert into $4($5, $3) select $1, $2 where not exists(select 1 from $4 where $5=$1)';
    $result = pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);

    return $result;
}
```

**setItemWorks:**

```
private function setItemWorks($table, $id, $field, $itemId, $fieldValue){

    $_1 = $itemId;
    $_2 = $fieldValue;

    $parameters = array($_1, $_2);

    // If the ID already exists, then update the name!
    $sql = 'update items set $name = $2 where id = $1;';
    pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);

    // Add ID and Name into table.
    $sql = 'insert into items(id, name) select $1, $2 where not exists(select 1 from items where id=$1)';
    $result = pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);

    return $result;
}
```

It seems that when I try putting 5 variables into the `pg_query_params` it doesn't work.

This is the error I am getting:

**Error:**

```
[20-Mar-2015 00:17:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$4"
LINE 1: update $4 set $3 = $2 where $5 = $1;
               ^ in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/ItemDatabase.php on line 139
```

**Edit:** The current answer I have put down is unsafe, any ideas how to make this safe whilst not being able to use `pg_query_params`?

Comment: Table names and column names cannot be parametrised. Use dynamic SQL for that. (when needed)

Comment: @wildplasser, Any good reference for how to do 'dynamic SQL' in a safe way. I've spent quite a bit of time going through a lot of PHP PostgreSQL functions and nothing seems to safely support parametrised table and column names.

Comment: Try:-   $sql = 'update '.$4 .'set'. $3 .' = '. $2 .'where' .$5 .' = ' .$1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening two cans of worms at once:

- **Dynamic SQL** while avoiding **SQL injection**
- **`UPSERT`** while solving race conditions with concurrent transactions

Both are tricky and the best solution depends on the details of your use case.

#### PL/pgSQL function

I suggest a server-side plpgsql function that encapsulates a clean solution for both problems:

- SQL injection is impossible.
- Concurrency issues are resolved.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_upsert
         (_tbl text, _id text, _fld text, _item_id int, _field_val text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _found int;
BEGIN
LOOP
   EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET %I = $1 WHERE %I = $2', _tbl, _fld, _id)
   USING   _field_val, _item_id;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _found = ROW_COUNT;
   IF _found > 0 THEN RETURN; END IF;

   BEGIN
      EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I(%I, %I) SELECT $1, $2', _tbl, _fld, _id)
      USING   _field_val, _item_id;
      RETURN;
   EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
      -- rarely happens, keep trying
   END;
END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_dynamic_upsert('foo', 'foo_id', 'foo_val', 3, 'new foo');
```

Or with [named parameter syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782199/functions-with-variable-number-of-input-parameters/16789179#16789179):

```
SELECT f_dynamic_upsert(_tbl := 'foo'
                      , _id := 'foo_id'
                      , _fld := 'foo_val'
                      , _item_id := 3
                      , _field_val :='new foo');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f6993/1) demonstrating it works.

More about dynamic SQL and SQL injection:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

Work for the Postgres `UPSERT` implementation is ongoing: `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT UPDATE`. With any luck, this will be in then next release 9.5. [Details in the Postgres Wiki.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT#RETURNING_behavior)
More about `UPSERT`:

- [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)
- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/17267423#17267423)
- [Issue with composite type in an UPSERT function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33322/3684)

#### PHP function

Could look something like this:

```
private function setItem($table, $id, $field, $itemId, $fieldValue) {
   $parameters = array($table, $id, $field, $itemId, $fieldValue)
   $sql = 'SELECT f_dynamic_upsert($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)';

   $result = pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);
   return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of parameters does not cause any issue with `pg_query_params()` (not with only 5 parameters, anyway), the source of the problem is your query.

As the error message says, the query parser does not expect a parameter at that position but a table name.

Query parameters can be used only instead of literal values (strings, numbers, `NULL` etc). Database, table and field names, SQL keywords, functions, operators and other syntax elements cannot be replaced by parameters.

You have to put the table names and fields in the query. This is why your method `setItemWorks()` runs and `setItemDoesNotWork()` fails.

There is a very good reason why `pg_query_params()` (and similar functions for other DBMS-es) accepts parameters only instead of literal values: the query using parameters is [parsed by the server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/spi-spi-prepare-params.html) and it has to be correct SQL.

The main purpose of the prepared queries is to do the SQL parsing only once when the same query is executed multiple times using different literal values. An additional advantage of the prepared queries is the protection against SQL injection. Because the values of the parameters are not directly inserted (quoted or not) in the query, the SQL injection is excluded. The values of the parameters are sent unescaped to the server; there is no reason to escape them because they do not become part of an SQL query any more.

Answer (score 0):

As per `wildplasser's` comment, I have assembled the function as follows and it now works fine:

```
private function setItemDoesNotWork($table, $id, $field, $itemId, $fieldValue){

    $_1 = $itemId;
    $_2 = $fieldValue;
    $_3 = $field;
    $_4 = $table;
    $_5 = $id;

    $parameters = array($_1, $_2);

    // If the ID already exists, then update the name!
    $sql = 'update ' . $_4 . ' set ' .$_3 . ' = $2 where ' . $_5 . ' = $1;';
    /*$result = */pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);

    // Add ID and Name into table.
    $sql = 'insert into ' . $_4 . '(' . $_5 . ',' . $_3 . ') select $1, $2 where not exists(select 1 from ' . $_4 . ' where ' . $_5 . '=$1)';

    $result = pg_query_params($this->database, $sql, $parameters);

    return $result;
}
```

**Edit:**

So this is unsafe, is there an easy way to make this function safe from SQL injection?

Comment: How do you protect your table and columns names against SQL injection?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, That is a good question. I was trying to use `pq_query_params` but in this context it cannot be used. 

I have left the question open as I am sure that my answer is the wrong one, even though it works. I know it is unsafe in its current state.