# How to sanitize my PostreSQL user input?

Tags: sql, database, sql-injection, plpgsql

i have a simple question: How would i go about sanitising my user input within my PLPGSQL function?

How is this generally done? I was not able to find detailed explanations. I want to defend myself against SQL injection.

I want to sanitise the search term. How would i do that? I read up on prepared statements, am not sure however, how to include them here. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Use parameters for all your queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you give me an example, or a reference to the correct ressource? here is my actual question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542789/querstion-regarding-using-keyword-in-my-sql-statement

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html