# In Postgres, how would I retrieve the default value of a column, preferably inline in an insert statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-null

Here's my example table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.cars
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,  
    make varchar(32) not null,
    model varchar(32),
    has_automatic_transmission boolean not null default false,
    created_on_date timestamptz not null DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

I have a function that allows my data service to insert a car into the database.   It looks like this:

```
drop function if exists cars_insert; 
 
create function cars_insert
(
    in make_in text,
    in model_in text,
    in has_automatic_transmission_in boolean,
    in created_on_date_in timestamptz 
)  
returns public.carsas 
$$
    declare result_set public.cars;
    begin   
        insert into cars
        (
            make,
            model,
            has_automatic_transmission,
            created_on_date
        ) 
        values 
        (
            make_in,
            model_in,
            has_automatic_transmission_in,
            created_on_date_in
        ) 
        returning * into result_set;  

        return result_set;
    end;
$$

language 'plpgsql';
```

This works really well until the service wants to insert a car with no value for has_automatic_transmission or created_on_date.  In that case they'd send null for those parameters and would expect the database to use a default value.  But instead the database rejects that null for obvious reasons (NOT NULL!).

What I want to do is have the insert routine do a coalesce to DEFAULT, but that doesn't work.  Here's the *logic* I want for the insert:

```
insert into cars
        (
            make,
            model,
            has_automatic_transmission,
            created_on_date
        ) 
        values 
        (
            make,
            model,
            COALESCE(has_automatic_transmission_in, DEFAULT),
            COALESCE(created_on_date_in, DEFAULT)
        )
```

How can I effectively achieve that?  Ideally it'd be some method I can apply inline to every column so that we don't need special knowledge of which columns do or don't have defaults, but I'll take anything at this point...

Except I'd like to avoid Dynamic SQL if possible.

Comment: Have you tried the last query? I should just work.

Comment: It should but it doesn't, sadly.  It returns the following error:

ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context
LINE 25:    coalesce(has_automatic_transmission, DEFAULT),

Comment: I also am not using dynamic sql unless I absolutely must.  I believe there must be a sane way to do this with the sql syntax as is

Comment: Ah, yes, I think I read the documentation too fast. We cannot use `DEFAULT` as an argument to a function. This SO answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39168579/10676716

Comment: Yeah I think the "DEFAULT" as a function param stops having the scope of the column and instead is being referenced within the scope of the column, which is dumb but hey that's how it be.

Comment: This solution only seems to address one column at a time.  Some of my tables have 5 or 6 columns with default values, so I'm not sure how I'd use this to address that scenario, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

While you need to pass values to a function, and want to insert default values instead of NULL dynamically, you could look them up like this (but see disclaimer below!):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cars_insert (make_in text
                                      , model_in text
                                      , has_automatic_transmission_in boolean
                                      , created_on_date_in timestamptz)  
  RETURNS public.cars AS
$func$
INSERT INTO cars(make, model, has_automatic_transmission, created_on_date) 
VALUES (make_in
      , model_in
      , COALESCE(has_automatic_transmission_in
               , (SELECT pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)::bool -- default_value
                  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
                  JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attrdef   d ON (d.adrelid, d.adnum) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum) 
                  WHERE  a.attrelid = 'public.cars'::regclass
                  AND    a.attname  = 'has_automatic_transmission'))
      , COALESCE(created_on_date_in
               , (SELECT pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)::timestamptz -- default_value
                  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
                  JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attrdef   d ON (d.adrelid, d.adnum) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum) 
                  WHERE  a.attrelid = 'public.cars'::regclass
                  AND    a.attname  = 'created_on_date'))
       )
RETURNING *;
$func$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=41e76f899932ef4df443ab9b9000cfec)*

You also have to know the column **type** to cast the text returned from [`pg_get_expr()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE).

I simplified to an SQL function, as nothing here requires PL/pgSQL.

See:

- [Get the default values of table columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146448/get-the-default-values-of-table-columns-in-postgres/8148177#8148177)

However, **this only works for constants** and types where a cast from `text` is defined. Other expressions (incl. functions) are not evaluated without dynamic SQL. `now()` in the example only *happens* to work by coincidence, as 'now' (ignoring parentheses) is a special input string for `timestamptz` that evaluates to the the same as the function `now()`. Misleading coincidence. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

To make it work for expressions that have to be evaluated, dynamic SQL is required - which you ruled out. But if dynamic SQL is allowed, it's much more efficient to build the target list of the `INSERT` dynamically and  omit columns that are supposed get default values. Or keep the target list constant and switch NULL values for the `DEFAULT` keyword. See:

- [Function to INSERT dynamic list of columns in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149387/function-to-insert-dynamic-list-of-columns-in-multiple-tables/11170583#11170583)
- [Test for null in function with varying parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353445/test-for-null-in-function-with-varying-parameters/17355733#17355733)
- [Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357)

Comment: Cool, but do you want to have two subqueries in every `INSERT`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I would rather *not* do it this way. It's just a proof of concept to answer the question asked. I would rather use a function with dynamic SQL or a trigger or handle NULL cases in the client. To be fair, each subquery is only executed for actual NULL input, so the performance impact is limited if NULL is a rare exception.

Answer (score 0):

I like Erwin's solution from the playfulness point of view, but it is quite expensive to have these subqueries in every `INSERT`. For practical purposes, I would recommend one of the following:

- Have four `INSERT` statements in the function, one for each combination of default/non-default arguments, and use `IF` statements to pick the right one.
- Don't use `DEFAULT`, but write a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that replaces NULLs with the appropriate value.

Of course this will add overhead too. You should benchmark the different options.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the suggestions made by previous commentators, I would write a function that generates, in a dynamic fashion, an insert function for each table.

The advantage of such approach is that the resulting insert function will not use dynamic SQL at all.

Function generating function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_generate_insert_function(tableid regclass) RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
DECLARE
    tablename text := tableid::text;
    funcname text := tablename || '_insert';

    ddl text := $ddl$
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s (%s) RETURNS %s LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $func$
        DECLARE
            result_set %s;
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO %s
            (
                %s
            )
            VALUES
            (
                %s
            )
            RETURNING * INTO result_set;

            RETURN result_set;
        END;
        $func$
    $ddl$;

    argument_list text := '';
    column_list   text := '';
    value_list    text := '';

    r record;
BEGIN

    FOR r IN
        SELECT attname nam, pg_catalog.format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) typ, pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid) def
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t
        ON t.oid = atttypid
        LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef
            ON adrelid = attrelid AND adnum = attnum AND atthasdef
        WHERE attrelid = tableid
          AND attnum > 0
    LOOP
        IF r.def LIKE 'nextval%' THEN
            CONTINUE;
        END IF;
        argument_list := argument_list || r.nam || '_in ' || r.typ || ',';
        column_list   := column_list   || r.nam || ',';
        IF r.def IS NULL THEN
            value_list   := value_list || r.nam || '_in,';
        ELSE
            value_list   := value_list || 'coalesce(' || r.nam || '_in,' || r.def || '),';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    argument_list := rtrim(argument_list, ',');
    column_list   := rtrim(column_list,   ',');
    value_list    := rtrim(value_list,    ',');

    EXECUTE format(ddl, funcname, argument_list, tablename, tablename, tablename, column_list, value_list);
END;
$$;
```

In your case, the resulting insert function will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cars_insert(make_in character varying, model_in character varying, has_automatic_transmission_in boolean, created_on_date_in timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS cars
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
        DECLARE
            result_set cars;
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO cars
            (
                make,model,has_automatic_transmission,created_on_date
            )
            VALUES
            (
                make_in,model_in,coalesce(has_automatic_transmission_in,false),coalesce(created_on_date_in,now())
            )
            RETURNING * INTO result_set;

            RETURN result_set;
        END;
        $function$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two Insert Statements; one where the Nullable columns are filled and another one which omits these columns as the default is only used if you do not reference the columns for insert.

Comment: this does not work when there are 6 columns with default values, as i'd have to have a copy for every permutation